# angularjs 1.5: How to enable auto-sort on key value object?

Tags: angularjs, migration

I recently upgraded my application from angularjs `v1.2` to `v1.5`. On `v1.2` angularjs was auto sorting key/value based objects in drop-down. But now as I upgraded to `1.5` every drown on my web app is showing items in random order (i.e. order coming from db). Is there any global parameter I can enable in `1.5` to get that auto-sort functionality again?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.days = {
    'key1': 'val1',
    'key7': 'val7',
    'key3': 'val3',
    'key9': 'val9',
    'key2': 'val2',
    'key5': 'val5',
    'key4': 'val4',
  };
});
```

I created plunk for both versions to ellaborate the problem clearly,

ver `1.2`
https://plnkr.co/edit/o0KJXjW25nlvDoKliHV0?p=preview

ver `1.5`
https://plnkr.co/edit/TudDwMhaAREhGVl5vz2c?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

[Always have a look at the migration guide before migrating to new version.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

**On `v1.2` angularjs was auto sorting key/value based objects in drop-down. But now as I upgraded to `1.5` every drown on my web app is showing items in random order.**

[From MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order.

In [AngularJS 1.5.0](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.js), `ng-options` directive used `getOptionValuesKeys()` method to get the array of keys. In that method, they used `for...in` that does not guarantee the order of iteration. That is why values in the drop-down are not sorted.

```
function getOptionValuesKeys(optionValues) {
      var optionValuesKeys;

      if (!keyName && isArrayLike(optionValues)) {
        optionValuesKeys = optionValues;
      } else {
        // if object, extract keys, in enumeration order, unsorted
        optionValuesKeys = [];
        for (var itemKey in optionValues) {
          if (optionValues.hasOwnProperty(itemKey) && itemKey.charAt(0) !== '$') {
            optionValuesKeys.push(itemKey);
          }
        }
      }
  return optionValuesKeys;   
}
```

In [AngularJS 1.2.28](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js), `ng-options` directive used `sortedKeys()` method to get the array of keys. They also used `for...in` in this method but sorted the array before returning it.

```
function sortedKeys(obj) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys.sort();
}
```

**Is there any global parameter I can enable in 1.5 to get that auto-sort functionality again?**

Yes, but may be you shouldn't change. To do this, you have to sort the return value of `getOptionValuesKeys` method in AngularJS source code. Modified method should look like this:

```
function getOptionValuesKeys(optionValues) {
       var optionValuesKeys;

       if (!keyName && isArrayLike(optionValues)) {
            optionValuesKeys = optionValues;
       } else {
            // if object, extract keys, in enumeration order, unsorted
            optionValuesKeys = [];
            for (var itemKey in optionValues) {
                if (optionValues.hasOwnProperty(itemKey) && itemKey.charAt(0) !== '$') {
                  optionValuesKeys.push(itemKey);
                }
            }
       }
  return optionValuesKeys.sort();
 }
```

**Additional question may arise: Why Angular team made this change?**

[Migrating from 1.3 to 1.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-3-to-1-4): Have a look at the changes in `ngOptions`

> Due to [7fda214c](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef), when iterating over an object's properties using the `(key, value)` in
>   `obj` syntax the order of the elements used to be sorted
>   alphabetically. This was an artificial attempt to create a
>   deterministic ordering since browsers don't guarantee the order. But
>   in practice this is not what people want and so this change iterates
>   over properties in the order they are returned by `Object.keys(obj)`,
>   which is almost always the order in which the properties were defined.

**Note:**

This change was made in AngularJS `1.4.0`, not in `1.5.0`. As you are migrating from `1.2.28`, you should consider all changes from version `1.3.0` to `1.5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/K85rxm?p=preview)

What you have to do is add one function `objectKeys` like this

```
$scope.objectKeys = function(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(k) { return obj[k] });
};
```

And then replace the object we were using on the ng-options with this function.

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in objectKeys(days)" />
```

Comment: Yeah, currently doing similar thing like this!!